# Как реализовать защиту от многократного голосования?

Tags: защита, php

Собственно сабж, в гугле просмотрел результаты, вплоть до *20* страницы, ничего дельного не нашел :(

Голосование открытое, т.е. без предварительной регистрации, без капчи и прочего, мне очень важно юзабилити.

**UPD:**

Моё голосование схоже с [этим](http://www.babevsbabe.com/)

Также выдаются две фотографии и нужно выбрать одну из них.

Comment: По ip-адресу или куки, какие еще могут быть варианты?

Comment: Это я и хочу узнать у вас :)

Comment: localstorage, webSql - это правда на JavaScript

Comment: @woland Это не подойдет, ведь можно стереть данные из localstorage, webSql.

Comment: @ReaGedCorp, IP тоже подменяется на раз

Comment: В принципе, никак. Против достаточно злобного пользователя вы ничего сделать не сможете: браузер с локальными данными и IP можно подменить (виртуальная машина с откатом состояния + прокси-сервер).

Попробуйте _заинтересовать_ пользователя, а? Взять не техникой (тут он вас обыграет), а социальной инженерией?

Comment: Спасибо, я тоже думал о СИ.

Comment: Вопрос решил, реализация: http://ktokruche.reaged.ru/battle-1-6

Answer (score 1):

Привязывайте к cookies и IP
т.е. каждый пользователь у Вас будет идентифицироваться примерно так

```
 $user = $_COOKIE['uniqCookie'].'|'.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

При этом, когда кто то голосует проверяйте в базе на наличие как куки так и ip, например.

```
$q = "select count(*) as user from votes where user like('%{$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']}') and user like('{$_COOKIE['uniqCookie']}%')";
```

Т.е. если бд вернет 0, то пользователь не голосовал, если 1 то голосовал.
Тут конечно есть минус, дважды с одного ip не проголосуешь, и не у всех IP свой (статический).

А так же отрезайте голоса которые отдаются через прокси. [мана как определить прокси](http://http-proxy.ru/FAQ/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8)

Так же можете вязаться к [кэшу](http://www.xakep.ru/post/61111/) браузера. По нему тоже можно идентифицировать пользователей, да и чистят его не всегда, при накрутке (в отличии от кукисов).

Еще, как вариант, ("защита" от школьников) храните часть идентификатора в localStorage браузера, и при передаче запроса на голосование, отправляйте его на сервер, там уже обрабатывайте подобно выше указаному коду.

Comment: @naym Спасибо за такой вариант, но это тоже все обходиться. 

Нужна защита, которая определяет накрутку не полагаясь на данные, которые сохраняются в браузере пользователя.

Comment: Тогда только IP адрес. Но тут прокси и защита обманута.
Конечно можете попробовать привязываться к таким данным как ОС, Версия браузера, установленные плагины на браузере (где то слышал, что эту инфу как то можно получить). Но это как то абстрактно, я думаю.

Проще прикрутить авторизацию к тому же вк, это не так долго, да и нажать пару привычных кнопок, не так уж и сложно. А там, уже и защититься проще.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую сделать авторизацию с помощью ВК. И как же тогда защититься?

p.s. Все же, авторизация в последнюю очередь, нужна защита без авторизаций.

Answer (score 0):

Почитать можно тут - [Интернет голосования, концепт защиты от накруток](http://habrahabr.ru/post/76025/)

Comment: Это я уже читал. Все обходиться за пару секунд.